# is it possible to register same servlet multiple times using ServletRegistrationBean in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets

I have a servlet which needs to be executed upon multiple `URLs`. Is it possible to register the same servlet but with different URLs? I need to set different `InitParameters` for each URL im configuring.

### DemoApplication.java

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);        
    }
    
    // Register Servlet
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        ServletRegistrationBean bean = new ServletRegistrationBean(new MyServlet(), "/Apple");
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
        params.put("THIRD_PARTY_ID","Apple");
        bean.setInitParameters(params);
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean2() {
        ServletRegistrationBean bean = new ServletRegistrationBean(
            new MyServlet(), "/Orange");
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
        params.put("THIRD_PARTY_ID","Orange");
        bean.setInitParameters(params);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

### MyServlet.java

```java
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet{
    
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("MyServlet's doGet() method is invoked.");
        doAction(req, resp);
    }

    private void doAction(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().write(getServletConfig().getInitParameter("THIRD_PARTY_ID"));
    }
}
```

Comment: If you register multiple and each has its own config it should work, what have you tried so far?